# Adding text to the end of multiple files, minus one line( Adding return 0; at the end of each program in C)

Tags: sed, cat, text-manipulation

I have a bunch of C programs from K&R and of course, no return statement. I was wondering if there was a way to cat to the end of each file (except one line before the end, so EOF - 1) the statement "\treturn 0;" including the tab before it and the newline after it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Unix, Linux, BSD, OSX, something else? Which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options (all of which are pointless and do exactly the same as `for f in *c; do echo -e "\treturn 0;" >> "$f"; done`):

1. Perl

   ```
   tmp=$(mktemp)
   for f in *c; do
       perl -lpe 'END{print "\treturn 0;"}' "$f" > $tmp && mv $tmp "$f"
   done
   ```
2. awk

   ```
   tmp=$(mktemp)
   for f in *.c; do
       awk '1;END{print "\treturn 0;"}' "$f" > $tmp && mv $tmp "$f"
   done
   ```
3. Cat the file into a temp file, add the line, and rename the temp file:

   ```
   tmp=$(mktemp)
   for f in *.c; do
       cat "$f" > $tmp;
       echo -e "\treturn 0;" >> $tmp
       mv $tmp "$f"
   done
   ```

Comment: I’m baffled as to why the OP accepted this answer, since it’s not what he asked for. All three options simply append the `return` statement to the file, which could be done as easily by `echo -e "\treturn 0" >> "$f"`. But the question asks how to _inject_ the `return` statement before the last line. (Also, you left off the semicolon.) P.S. Congratulations on winning the election.

Comment: @Scott no more baffled than I to tell you the truth. As for `echo >> file` I had a serious problem between the keyboard and my brain there. For some reason, which I can no longer remember, I thought these approaches do something different. Presumably I was thinking of something like what your answer does and then decided to reinvent the wheel. I can't do much about it since it's accepted but you may as well give it a downvote so at least yours will rise up. P.S. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

1. Unix:

   ```
   tmp=$(mktemp)
   for f in *c; do
       head --lines=-1 "$f" > "$tmp"
       echo -e "\treturn 0;" >> "$tmp"
       tail -1 "$f" >> "$tmp"
       mv "$tmp" "$f"
   done
   ```
2. awk:

   ```
   tmp=$(mktemp)
   for f in *.c; do
       awk 'NR > 1 { print prev_line; }
                   { prev_line = $0; }
               END { print "\treturn 0;"; print; }' "$f" > "$tmp" \
       &&  mv "$tmp" "$f"
   done
   ```
3. sed:

   ```
   for f in *.c; do
       sed -i '$i\
   \treturn 0;' "$f"
   done
   ```